# How will the third for loop work out?

Tags: java

I have a question about the third for loop, how does it work please ?

```
public void outputBarChart()
{
    System.out.println("Grade Distribution: \n");

    int frequency[] = new int[11];

    for(int oneGrade : grade)
    {
        ++frequency[oneGrade / 10];
    }

   for (int count = 0; count < frequency.length; count++)
   {
       if (count == 10) {
           System.out.println("100");
       }
       else {
           System.out.printf("%02d-%02d: ",
                   count*10, count*10 + 9);
       }

        //the third for loop here !
        for (int star = 0; star < frequency[count]; star++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

   }
}
```

The problem is I don't know the mechanics how it print out stars.

Comment: Can you be specific about your confusion? It just prints `frequency[count]` stars in a row

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? It's a simple for loop which print a `*` at each iteration.

Comment: Run the debugger, trace through the execution and see what happens.

Comment: I think if someone is having trouble understanding that then they are probably not yet on good terms with a debugger.

Comment: I was confused because I didn't know when the third "for" loop back to the second, then go to the third again, the 3rd loop just start all over again instead of where it's left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well lets go through the code then:

The second for loop which contains the third for-loop will loop 11 times since thats the length of frequencey. Okay that was easy.

Now the third for-loop iterates `frequency[count]` times, we don't know this value, but we know that it is an integer. So what third loop will do is simply to print out a star `frequency[count]` times. After that we're done with the third loop and a newline is printed by the second loop.

```
System.out.println("*" * frequency[count]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the walk-through, the debugger worked very well, I should have tried that first.

Answer (score 1):

The loop will take the variable `star` and loop and increment until it reaches the value of `frequency[count]`. So it will run the loop the same number of times as the value stored in `frequency[count]`.

Each loop iteration it prints a star. At the end it prints a blank line.

The result is printing the number of stars as `frequency[count]` on a line.